# How do I convert an array of strings into append-able list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have parsed through a CSV file and stored it as an array of strings. I'd like to add an item to each sub-array if certain conditions have been met, as shown below. However, I am not able to use the `.add()` method and get a "Cannot resolve method" message in my IDE. To try to get around this, I attempted to create a new arraylist in which I placed the contents of the string array, but the problem persisted. How do I make it so that I can add an item to each sublist?

```html
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Application {
    /**
     * Main entry of the application.
     *
     * @param args This should be empty
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "/IUCNListV2.csv";
        List<String[]> listAnimal =
        ReadCSV.readFileAndParseSkipFirstline(Application.class.getResourceAsStream(csvFile));


        List<String[]> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String [] text : listAnimal) {
            list2.add(text);
        }
        
        for(String[] subList: list2)
            if (null != subList && subList[4].equals("x") &&
                    subList[5].equals("y")) {
                subList.add("z");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: array in java do not have any method like add, java.util.List supports method add not array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add element in string array directly. You can follow those steps

- You can create list from string array
- Add the element in list
- Again convert list to array
- Update the outer list

```
for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
    String[] subList = list2.get(i);
    if (null != subList && subList[4].equals("x") &&
                    subList[5].equals("y")) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(subList)); // create a list
        list.add("z"); // add in list
        list2.set(i, list.toArray(new String[0])) // create array from list and update parent list
    }
}
```

Or create a `List<List<String>>` from `List<String[]>` first then add in inner list

Answer (score 0):

To convert an array of String to ArrayList simply use this

```
String[] x = {"example1","example2"};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the add method on arrays, because the add method is in the List interface, but you can use List objects in your other list like this, for this solution:

```
public class Application {
    /**
     * Main entry of the application.
     *
     * @param args This should be empty
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "/IUCNListV2.csv";
        List<List<String>> listAnimal =
                ReadCSV.readFileAndParseSkipFirstline(Application.class.getResourceAsStream(csvFile));


        List<List<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.addAll(listAnimal);

        for(List<String> subList: list2)
            if (null != subList && subList.get(4).equals("x") &&
                    subList.get(5).equals("y")) {
                subList.add("z");
            }
    }
}
```